# Who is Carmine in A Bronx Tale?

Tags: character, a-bronx-tale

At the end of *A Bronx Tale (1993)*, Joe Pesci makes a cameo appearance at...

> Sonny's funeral

...introducing himself to Calogero as Carmine and asking if he remembered him.

Was this character actually shown earlier in the movie, and was he played by Joe Pesci himself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ax explained on [the movie's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Bronx_Tale):

> When the crowd disperses, a lone man, Carmine, visits the funeral, claiming that Sonny once saved his life as well. **Calogero does not recognize Carmine until he sees a scar on his forehead and realizes he was the man being assaulted whom Sonny had defended when he committed the murder.** Carmine tells Calogero that he is filling in for Sonny in the neighborhood for the time being, and promises Calogero help should he ever need. Carmine leaves just as Lorenzo unexpectedly arrives to pay his respects to Sonny. Lorenzo thanks him for saving his son's life and admits that he had never hated him, but that he had resented him for making Calogero grow up so quickly. Calogero and his father walk home together as Calogero narrates the lessons he learned from his two mentors.